# Create and write to a file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, pid

I've been trying everything in this forum I can see. Nothing works right. This is what I have:

```
gnome-terminal (open new terminal execute a command in said terminal) &  
pid=$!  
echo "$pid"
```

this gives me a printout in terminal of the pid just fine. but when I add:

```
echo $pid >> myfile.txt
```

It doesn't make the txt file in the directory this whole script sits in or write to it for that matter. This is all in a script .sh.
Can someone give me like a complete explanation of how I need to go about doing this?

Comment: Re: "It doesn't make the txt file **in the directory this whole script sits in**": Why would it? `myfile.txt` means "a file named `myfile.txt` in the current working directory", which has nothing to do with the directory the script sits in. (Imagine that you typed `echo $pid >> myfile.txt` at the interactive prompt. Would you expect it to create a file named `myfile.txt` in the directory that Bash sits in?)

Comment: @ruakh I freaking love you! LOL thanks the logic was so simple it was staring me in the face hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a text editor (vi/m, nano, gedit..)
2. The first line of the script will be

   `#! /bin/bash`
3. Get familiar with [bash scripting](https://ss64.com/bash/).
4. Then execute the file as

   `./filename`
5. If the permission is denied, read about chmod command, type

   `chmod 755 filename`

   then, `./filename`

Comment: You have to indent code within lists four *more* spaces, or it doesn't show up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "It doesn't make the txt file **in the directory this whole script sits in**": Why would it? `myfile.txt` means "a file named `myfile.txt` in the current working directory", which has nothing to do with the directory the script sits in. (Imagine that you typed `echo $pid >> myfile.txt` at the interactive prompt. Would you expect it to create a file named `myfile.txt` in the directory that Bash sits in?) – ruakh